# Is there a wiring control like the Yahoo Pipes interface for WinForms?

Tags: .net, winforms, controls

My application's user interface needs to be built soon and the data being represented is  chainable; most components have inputs and outputs and can be freely wired together as necessary. Yahoo Pipes is the style of interface I think I need but I'm having trouble finding something suitable for WinForms. TreeGX looks interesting but it only flows outwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Netron project

[www.orbifold.net/netron/](http://www.orbifold.net/netron/)

http://www.orbifold.net/default/?page_id=1273

UPDATE:

This one is open source but I haven't tried it

http://www.piccolo2d.org

Answer (score 2):

Northwood's [GoDiagram](http://www.northwoods.com/GO/dotnet.htm) was quite good when I tried it in 2002.